# Dbeaver SQL Common Expression Table Question

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]
I am trying to create a table in Dbeaver and I have encountered an issue. I have posted my code below. My code works fine if a well has completion types of both 'Frac' of 'MSFRAC'.However, this well with a uwi= '100042204410W500' has only 'MSFRAC' as completion type. When I run my code, it shows nothing in output (image 2).I wrote a small part of code at the top to check this well's information and you can see the output shows that all well completion types are MSFRAC.

What cause this empty output issue? As you can see here, I am using common expression tables for key words "FRAC","MSFRAC",and"%PERF". So my assumption is if FRAC and %PERF% has no record for this well, even tho MSFRAC has data, it will cause the output to be empty???

Please help!!!! Much Appreciated1

[image]

```
WITH frac as (
    SELECT
     c.uwi,
    case 
            when AVG(c.base_depth - c.top_depth) =0
            then null
            else AVG(c.base_depth - c.top_depth)        
    end AS Avg_Frac_Stage_Spacing,
    COUNT(c.completion_type) AS Frac_Stage_Count,
    min(c.completion_date) as Min_Completion_Date,
    max(c.completion_date) as Max_Completion_Date
    FROM
     well_completion AS c
    WHERE
     c.completion_type = 'FRAC' 
     --or c.completion_type='MSFRAC'
    GROUP BY
    c.uwi
    ),
    msfrac as (
    SELECT
     c.uwi,
    case 
            when max(c.base_depth - c.top_depth) >500
            then (sum(c.base_depth)-sum(c.top_depth)-max(c.base_depth - c.top_depth))/nullif((count(c.completion_type)-1),0)
            else AVG(c.base_depth - c.top_depth)        
    end AS Avg_Msfrac_Stage_Spacing,
    case 
            when max(c.base_depth - c.top_depth) >500
            then count(c.completion_type)-1
            else count(c.completion_type)
    end AS Msfrac_Stage_Count
    FROM
     well_completion AS c
    WHERE
     c.completion_type = 'MSFRAC' 
     --or c.completion_type='MSFRAC'
    GROUP BY
    c.uwi
    ),
    jetperf as (
    SELECT
     c.uwi,
     COUNT(c.completion_type) AS Perf_Count,
     avg(c.base_depth-c.top_depth ) as Avg_cluster_interval
     --Avg(c.x_perf_shots) as SPM
     --Avg((c.base_depth - c.top_depth)*(c.x_perf_shots)) as Avg_counts_per_cluster
    FROM
     well_completion AS c
    WHERE
     c.completion_type like '%PERF%' 
     --and (c.base_depth - c.top_depth) <= 2
    GROUP BY
    c.uwi
    )
    select
     f.uwi,
     f.Frac_Stage_Count+m.Msfrac_Stage_Count as Stage_Count,
     f.Min_Completion_Date,
     f.Max_Completion_Date,
    (m.Avg_Msfrac_Stage_Spacing*m.Msfrac_Stage_Count+f.Avg_Frac_Stage_Spacing*f.Frac_Stage_Count)/(m.Msfrac_Stage_Count+f.Frac_Stage_Count) as Stage_Spacing,
     --f.completion_strat_unit_id,
     round(j.Perf_count/(f.Frac_Stage_Count+m.Msfrac_Stage_Count),2) as Avg_number_of_clusters,
     j.Avg_cluster_interval,
     j.perf_Count,
     --j.SPM,
     --j.Avg_counts_per_cluster,
     j.Avg_cluster_interval/f.Avg_frac_stage_spacing as completion_multipledividebysingle_ratio,
     (f.Avg_Frac_Stage_Spacing+m.Avg_Msfrac_Stage_Spacing)/j.Perf_Count *(f.Frac_Stage_Count+m.Msfrac_Stage_Count) AS Avg_cluster_spacing,
     m.Avg_Msfrac_Stage_Spacing,
     ihs_ppdm3_own1.well.profile_type as Profile_type,
     ihs_ppdm3_own1.well."operator" as Operator, 
     ihs_ppdm3_own1.well.province_state as Province_state,
     ihs_ppdm3_own1.well.x_td_tvd as x_td_tvd,
     ihs_ppdm3_own1.well.max_tvd as max_tvd,
     ihs_ppdm3_own1.well.td_strat_unit_id as td_strat_unit
    FROM
     frac as f
      inner join
     jetperf as j
      ON
       f.uwi = j.uwi
     inner join 
     ihs_ppdm3_own1.well
      ON
       ihs_ppdm3_own1.well.uwi=f.uwi
     inner join 
     msfrac as m
      ON
     m.uwi=f.uwi
     where ihs_ppdm3_own1.well.profile_type ='H'and f.uwi ='100042204410W500'
```

Comment: This is basically just a code dump with almost no effort to give a clear problem statement.  Please tell us exactly what is wrong with your CTE.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi Tim, i thought i explained my issue using 2 images. Basically, it does not show any output for a well with completion_type "MSFRAC".

Comment: and this is postgres. My query is to look for the different info of each well and use CTE to calculate some extra data using output data. This query can work well for wells that have "perf","frac" and "msfrac" defined. I did a test using the well on the image and i realize the query does not output anything. Then i checked the completion_type and realize it only has "MSFRAC" defined. What confuses me is why it does not output the MSFRAC info when I have "MSFRAC" CTE defined in the query. Does this make sense to you guys? Please let me know.

Comment: @cddt Please help

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it is postgres i am using. Hope that is DBMS you are talking about.

Comment: for some reason, my query returns empty values for all columns on a certain well. But it will return results for other wells. What can be the issue with this specific well? Does it have empty or null data that causes the query results to be all empty?